# NOT a Clickbait

Tags: riddle

Here comes another Riley!

> My infix is who you are
>
> My prefix is my infix's alpha
>
> My suffix is a short little insect
>
> And me you shall not dissect!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Adamant

My infix is who you are

> **Man** - General word to represent a human being. 
>  Original answer *Am* - First person singular of the verb *to be*, e.g, "I am".

My prefix is my infix's alpha

> **Adam** - from the Bible, first man (alpha male) created by God.

My suffix is a short little insect

> **Ant**

And me you shall not dissect!

> **Adamant** - a legendary rock or mineral (think of Wolverine's adamantium).

Title

> The author appears to be adamant in their assertion. Also, adamant translates from Greek via Latin as "not to be tamed" which could tie in with the wording of the title

Comment: I believe, "am" is not the intended infix :)

Comment: @ThomasBlue Yes, I think you are right actually, I've updated appropriately.

Comment: Nicely done! +1 +tick